# How to compare char type pointers using _Bool function?

Tags: c, pointers, boolean, boolean-expression

I should check if 2 arrays are equal using exact function _Bool areEqual(char *str1,char *str2). My code  terminates. What should I do in order to effectively use _Bool function to print true (if they are equal) and false( not equal).

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

_Bool areEqual(char* str1, char* str2) {

  while (str1 != '\0') {

    if (str1 == str2) {
      str1++;

      if (str1 = '\0') {
        return true;
      }
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

int  main() {

  char arr[] = "abcdef";
  char* ptr = "abcdef";

  areEqual(arr, ptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can store the return value of the function into a variable. Or you can use the return value as a condition for `if`.

Comment: @Gerhardh, thank you. The method you are saying I can use with void, int functions. But what is the point  to use _Bool function here?

Comment: No, you cannot do this with functions with `void` return type as they do not provide any return value. The point is to tell you if they are equal or not. For pure true/false values why would you need any other type than `_Bool`? Just store it in a `_Bool` variable instead of `int` etc. Or just use it in any expression where a boolean value is suitable.

Comment: `if(str1='\0')` Pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: Anyway, in order to write this function you must first study pointers. Start there, before moving on to C strings.

Comment: `str1!='\0'` and as Lundin mentioned also `str1='\0'` are incorrect conditions. `str1` is a pointer, not a `char`. And you probably do not intent to make an assignment inside a condition here.

Comment: Well, _all_ of the `if` statements are incorrect since these are pointers. The solution is to study how pointers work before using them.

Comment: You probably want `if(str1==str2)` -> `if (strcmp(str1,str2) == 0)`. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your beginner's C text book.

Comment: BTW: what return value do you expect for `areEqual(arr, ptr)`?

Comment: I formatted your code properly. Poorly formatted code is hard to understand, and it's even harder for beginners.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It appears that they are rather trying to implement `strcmp` manually, as part of an exercise.

Comment: @Lundin you're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to simplify bool is an alias to _Bool so they are similar.

Secondly, your function AreEqual is actually comparing the content of s1 with the first charachter of s2, if  you want to compare all the content of the strings you need to iterate on both

```
_Bool areEqual(char *s1, char *s2)
{
   int i = 0;

   while (s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0') {
         if (s1[i] != s2[i])
             return false;
         i++;
    }
    if (s1[i] != '\0' || s2[i] != '\0') //string with different length
        return false;
    return true
}
```

Finaly to print the corresponding result you just need to check the return of your function

```
if (areEqual(str1, str2) == true)
    printf("True");
else
    printf("False");
```